# How to make code more efficient in terms of speed

Tags: python, pandas, algorithm, performance, parallel-processing

Suppose we have a pickle file called `pickle_list.pkl` which contains 23 pandas data frames. Also `df_combined` is a concatenation of all those data frames. Suppose that the shape of `df_combined` is `(1000000, 5000)`. Is there a more efficient way of running the following block of code? Maybe some type of parallelization could work?

Right now it is on row 69000 and it has been running for a day.

```
import pickle
import pandas as pd
df_list = pd.read_pickle(r'pickle_list.pkl')
df_combined = pd.concat(df_list, ignore_index=True)

for row in df_combined.itertuples():
    print(row.Index)
    id = row.id
    df_test= df_combined[df_combined['id']==str(id)]
```

Comment: Use a groupby. This operation runs in quadratic time. Besides this, note that `row` is unused in your code.

Comment: @JérômeRichard: I edited by code. It does use row. How would I use groupby?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `groupby` to create a dictionary efficiently then used to fetch the required identifiers quickly. Here is an untested example to show the idea:

```py
import pickle
import pandas as pd
df_list = pd.read_pickle(r'pickle_list.pkl')
df_combined = pd.concat(df_list, ignore_index=True)

all_groups = {ident:df for ident,df in df_combined.groupby('id')}

for row in df_combined.itertuples():
    id = row.id
    # You may need to add a condition before if the searched ID does not exist
    df_test = all_groups[str(id)]
```

Comment: Would the process described here speed things up also: https://towardsdatascience.com/how-to-make-your-pandas-loop-71-803-times-faster-805030df4f06

Comment: Or here: https://natedong72.medium.com/parallelize-and-accelerate-your-pandas-dataframes-85d6ceb1aa1f#:~:text=Modin%20simply%20divides%20a%20Python,of%20any%20size%20and%20shape

Comment: Regarding what you want to do with `df_test`, it may or may not help. Especially parallelisation with Pandas. Many library claim to be much faster in parallel, but in practice, this is a different story... Not to mention that they have additional constraints and do not always provide basic features provided by pandas. The best is to try yourself.

Comment: did you mean `all_groups = {ident:df for ident,df in df_combined.groupby('id')}`

Comment: Right. Fixed. Thank you.